# Escape % when using :!echo %HOME% with cmd.exe

Tags: terminal, microsoft-windows

When I run:

```
:!echo %HOME%
```

On Windows 10 I expected to get the location of my home directory.

But Vim interpret the symbol `%` as the current file name, in-spite of the `!` in front of `echo`.

Hence, I get:

```
<current_file_name>HOME<current_file_name>
```

Any hints on how to fix it?

Comment: I know it's windows, but does `$HOME` not work?

Comment: It works with the Powershell that use the $ symbol to show the content of environmental variables, but cmd.exe uses the syntax with double %. So, no, $HOME does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: You need to escape the `%`, e.g. use `exe ':!echo ' .. shellescape('%HOME%',1)`. But any environment variable that has been exported and vim knows about, should also be available as `$variable` inside vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it works if you escape `%` with `\`

```
:!echo \%home\%
```